# Exclude Retweets using LinqToTwitter

Tags: twitter, linq-to-twitter

My LinqToTwitter class can not exclude retweets.

```
var srch = (from search in twitterCtx.Search where search.Type == SearchType.Search && search.Query == term && search.Count == 100 select search).SingleOrDefault();
```

There is no option about `search.IncludeRetweets==false`.

How can I do a search with that? Should I try another class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Twitter API doesn't offer that option, so neither does LINQ to Twitter. That said, here's what you can do:

1. Perform your search query as normal. It will contain retweets.
2. Perform a LINQ to Objects query on the results using a where clause that sets the condition of RetweetedStatus.StatusID == 0, like this:

   ```
   var nonRetweetedStatuses =
       (from tweet in searchResponse.Statuses
        where tweet.RetweetedStatus.StatusID == 0
        select tweet)
       .ToList();
   ```

The reason why I suggested using the where clause like this is because LINQ to Twitter instantiates a Status for RetweetedStatus, regardless of whether it exists or not. However, the contents of that Status are the default values of each properties type. Since StatusID will never be 0 for a valid retweet, this works. You could also filter on another field like Text == null and it would still work.

Comment: i didnt know that, twitter not supports that. thanks. i will try -RT in search query.

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your search term `exclude:replies` and/or `exclude:retweets`:

```
term = term + " exclude:replies exclude:retweets";
```